# Numpy array transformation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy array of float numbers. Step between numbers is about (sometimes bigger or smaller) multiple of `2.17e-06`.

```
[4.62236694, 4.62236910, 4.62237128, 4.62237562, 4.62237996,
 4.62238430, 4.62238864, 4.62239298, 4.62239732, 4.62239950,
 4.62240166, 4.62240384, 4.62240600, 4.62241034, 4.62241250]
```

What I need is to transform the array by inserting new numbers between existing so step between every number became equal about `2.17e-06`.

I tried to create new array with desired step, but this does not work because I have to keep numbers from original array precisely.

I can solve the task by simple python "for" loop, but for my dataset it takes an hour to proceed and I need to perform it much faster.

Is there a numpy way to perform such kind of array transformation?

I can imagine that array should be sparsed like this:

```
[4.62236476, 4.62236694, 4.62236910, 4.62237128, nan, 4.62237562, nan, 4.62237996,
 nan, 4.62238430, nan, 4.62238864, nan, 4.62239298, nan, 4.62239732,
 4.62239950, 4.62240166, 4.62240384, 4.62240600, nan, 4.62241034, 4.62241250,
 4.62241468, nan, 4.62241902, 4.62242120, 4.62242336, 4.62242554, 4.62242770,
 4.62242988, 4.62243204]
```

here I put `nan` value every where I need new number.

And after fill `nan`s with `previous number + 2.17e-06`.

```
[... 4.62237128, nan, 4.62237562, ...] -> [... 4.62237128, 4.62237345, 4.62237562, ...]
```

Comment: why dont you create new array with numpy  `np.arange(min(array), max(array), step)`

Comment: "*I have to keep numbers from original array precisely.*"

Comment: @Nagakiran When I create new array, new numbers does not match original ones (that already were in original array), difference is small but critical for me.

Comment: can you some example array in it and show expected, it would be feasible for developers to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you do what @Naga kiran suggested but then replace the values in the upsampled array with the values in the original array?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([4.62236694, 4.62236910, 4.62237128, 4.62237562,])
upsamle = np.arange(arr.min(), arr.max()+2.17e-6, step = 2.17e-6)
print(f'upsamle = \n{upsamle}')
for value in arr:
    upsamle[np.argmin(np.abs(upsamle-value))] = value
print(f'upsamle = \n{upsamle}')
```

output:

```
upsamle = 
[4.62236694 4.62236911 4.62237128 4.62237345 4.62237562]
upsamle = 
[4.62236694 4.6223691  4.62237128 4.62237345 4.62237562]
```

Notice that before the replacement, the second value (4.62236911) is different than the one in the original array but is l8r replaced with the appropriate value thus adhering to your requirement. This method can be sped up by replacing the for loop with either an outer vector operation to compute the distance of each value in 'arr' to each value in 'upsampled' or using the numba package with the for loop.

Here's some tests on your example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

arr = np.array([4.62236694, 4.62236910, 4.62237128, 4.62237562, 4.62237996,
                4.62238430, 4.62238864, 4.62239298, 4.62239732, 4.62239950,
                4.62240166, 4.62240384, 4.62240600, 4.62241034, 4.62241250])
upsampled = np.arange(arr.min(), arr.max()+2.17e-6, step = 2.17e-6)

def process_array(upsampled, arr):
    for value in arr:
        upsampled[np.argmin(np.abs(upsampled-value))] = value
    return upsampled

@njit(parallel = True)
def process_array_jit(upsampled, arr):
    for value in arr:
        upsampled[np.argmin(np.abs(upsampled-value))] = value
    return upsampled

def process_array_vec(upsampled, arr):
    distances = np.abs(upsampled[None, :] - arr[:, None])
    replace   = np.argmin(distances, axis = 1)
    upsampled[replace] = arr
    return upsampled

print('python for loop')
%timeit process_array(upsampled, arr)
print('numba for loop')
%timeit process_array_jit(upsampled, arr)
print('numpy vector operation')
%timeit process_array_vec(upsampled, arr)
```

output:

```
python for loop
The slowest run took 7.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 5: 70.3 µs per loop
numba for loop
The slowest run took 19672.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 5: 24 µs per loop
numpy vector operation
The slowest run took 12.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 5.71 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to merge your array with an arrangement of values that you get with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) then mask the values properly such that you only remove elements from the second array (the arrangement) and not the initial one.

```
>>> step = 2.17e-06
>>> halfstep = step / 2
```

Note: I have preprocessed the input array `x` with `x -= x[0]`.

Prepare the arangement:

```
>>> n = 4.556e-05 // step
>>> filled = np.arange(n)*step
array([0.000e+00, 2.170e-06, 4.340e-06, 6.510e-06, 8.680e-06, 1.085e-05,
       1.302e-05, 1.519e-05, 1.736e-05, 1.953e-05, 2.170e-05, 2.387e-05,
       2.604e-05, 2.821e-05, 3.038e-05, 3.255e-05, 3.472e-05, 3.689e-05,
       3.906e-05, 4.123e-05])
```

Merge the two and sort:

```
>>> merged = np.concatenate((filled, x))

>>> argsort = np.argsort(merged)
array([ 0, 20, 21,  1,  2, 22,  3, 23,  4,  5, 24,  6,  7,  8, 25,  9, 26,
       10, 11, 27, 12, 13, 14, 28, 15, 29, 16, 30, 17, 31, 32, 18, 19, 33,
       34])

>>> sort = merged[argsort]
array([0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.160e-06, 2.170e-06, 4.340e-06, 4.340e-06,
       6.510e-06, 8.680e-06, 8.680e-06, 1.085e-05, 1.302e-05, 1.302e-05,
       1.519e-05, 1.736e-05, 1.736e-05, 1.953e-05, 2.170e-05, 2.170e-05,
       2.387e-05, 2.604e-05, 2.604e-05, 2.821e-05, 3.038e-05, 3.038e-05,
       3.255e-05, 3.256e-05, 3.472e-05, 3.472e-05, 3.689e-05, 3.690e-05,
       3.906e-05, 3.906e-05, 4.123e-05, 4.340e-05, 4.556e-05])
```

Construct the two masks: `m1` will keep the values from `x` while `m2` will remove the values from `filled` that are too close to `x`'s values.

- `m1` is created by simply masking `argsort`:

  ```
  >>> m1 = argsort >= n
  array([False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
         False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
         False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
         True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])
  ```
- While `m2` is a little trickier, we need to compute the step-1 difference in both ways, `left` and `right`. Then compute the boolean mask `left & right`:

  ```
  >>> left = np.diff(sort, prepend=0) > halfstep
  >>> right = np.diff(sort, append=0) > halfstep
  >>> m2 = np.logical_and(left, right)
  array([False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
         True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
         True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
         False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False])
  ```

Finally, you can apply `m1 | m2` on the sorted merged array `sort`:

```
>>> mask = np.logical_or(m1, m2) == 1
>>> sort[mask]
array([0.000e+00, 2.160e-06, 4.340e-06, 6.510e-06, 8.680e-06, 1.085e-05,
       1.302e-05, 1.519e-05, 1.736e-05, 1.953e-05, 2.170e-05, 2.387e-05,
       2.604e-05, 2.821e-05, 3.038e-05, 3.256e-05, 3.472e-05, 3.690e-05,
       3.906e-05, 4.123e-05, 4.340e-05, 4.556e-05])
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, I have collected couple of tricks from it that I will definitely use in future. But it works a bit slow as I could check it.

Comment: Sure thing, I agree the method is not very practical. I was experimenting a bit to see if this method was feasible.